# How to enable SSL in tomcat 8.5 using x.509 CA certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to enable SSL in tomcat 8.5 using x. 509 CA certificate.

Please provide me the complete step by step procedure.

1. Steps to install x.509 certificate
2. Steps to change settings in server.xml file

Environment:
RHEL7. 6 Linux azure cloud instance
Already have generated test x. 509 certificate p01.cert, cacert.pem.

Thanks in advance, 
Maduraipandian Manivel.

Comment: For enabling SSL you need a private key matching the public key in the certificate.

Comment: How to get the same

Comment: I generated the certificate after generating server.csr file only.